# CS50 clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header, cs50, function-declaration

I'm taking the course Harvard CS50x and this is the caesar problem set.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

 int main(int argc, string argv[])
 {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Nope\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int k = atoi(argv[1]);

    if (k < 0)
    {
        printf("Nope\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        string code = GetString();

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(code); i < n; i++)
            {
                if islower(code[i])
                    printf("%c", (((code[i] + k) - 97) % 26) + 97);
                else if isupper(code[i])
                    printf("%c", (((code[i] + k) - 65) % 26) + 65);
                else
                    printf("%c", code[i]);
            }
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
    }
 }
```

I don't understand what the problem is with this code but when I try to compile I get this:
[image: The IDE is AWS Cloud9]

Comment: Please don't add unrelated tags to questions. The 5 tags limit is a *limit*, not a requirement in case that was unclear.

Comment: @Vish G These if statements if islower(code[i])and else if isupper(code[i])  shall not compile. You have to enclose in parentheses the expression that is used in the if statement.

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>` to get `atoi`. And `GetString` should be `get_string`

Comment: See https://manual.cs50.io/

Answer (score 0):

To use the function `atoi` you need to include the header `<stdlib.h>`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

It seems the function `GetString` is not declared in the header `<cs50.h>`. Instead try to use the function `get_string`. For example

```
string code = get_string( "Enter a text: " );
```

These if statements

```
            if islower(code[i])
                printf("%c", (((code[i] + k) - 97) % 26) + 97);
            else if isupper(code[i])
```

are incorrect. Expressions used in if statements shall be enclosed in pafrentheses. For example

```
            if ( islower( ( unsigned char )code[i] ) )
                printf("%c", (((code[i] + k) - 97) % 26) + 97);
            else if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )code[i] ) )
```

Also it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like for example `97` or `65`. Instead use `'a'` and `'A'`.

Comment: that gives the following error https://gyazo.com/30b00f95ff914ca68f806e945c3e2e01 and when I capitalize the g I get this https://gyazo.com/161a41db1726ebe381173fcf1d46bab5

Comment: @VishG I showed you how the function get_string shall be called. You have to specify an argument as some prompt.

Comment: I don't know what to put as the argument though

Comment: @VishG I showed in my answer. What is the problem? You can place any text that will be used as a prompt.